# Error handling in a loop that outputs a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

## Problem

I am trying to write a loop in R where I am anticipating some errors. Instead of stopping the loop, I am trying to figure out a way to capture the error message and include that information in the output and continue the loop.

NOTE about data: [This](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/data.csv) data is from the NOAA website and it is the Southern Oscillation Index data. The second set is trivial (data2) and is presented solely to generate an error.

Here is a slightly trivial example of the type of loop I am trying to create. Take some data from the web, perform some manipulations on it, store it (as `df`) then get more data, perform the same manipulation and append it (via `rbind`) to the first data:

```
data_spec <- c("data")
df <- c()
for (i in data_spec){
  raw <- read.csv(
    paste0("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/",i,".csv"),
           skip = 2, col.names = c("Date","SOI") )
  u <- data.frame(data_spec = i, mean_soi = mean(raw$SOI))
  df <- rbind(df, u)
}
```

Because https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/data2.csv is not a valid url, the loop stops and throws an error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open URL
>   'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/data2.csv':
>   HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

## Expected Output

I am trying to achieve an output like this where the error message is captured as object and appended accordingly:

```
  data_spec                                             mean_soi
1      data                                            0.1223618
2     data2 Error in file(file, rt) : cannot open the connection
```

## Attempts to figure this out

So I think I am clear that I need to use `tryCatch` here. If I use it like so:

```
data_spec <- c("data", "data2")
df <- c()
for (i in data_spec){
  tryCatch({
  raw <- read.csv(
    paste0("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/",i,".csv"),
    skip = 2, col.names = c("Date","SOI") )
  u <- data.frame(data_spec = i, mean_soi = mean(raw$SOI))
  df <- rbind(df, u)
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}
```

the loop continues along, but the error message isn't captured in the output (not that I was expecting this here).

Another option is to use the function outputted from: `demo(error.catching)`. I modified that function a little so that the error message is captured:

```
tryCatch_mod <- function(expr)
{
  W <- NULL
  w.handler <- function(w){ # warning handler
    W <<- w
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  }
  temp <- list(value = withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) e),
                                   warning = w.handler),
       warning = W)

  unlist(temp[[2]])$message
}
```

This outputs an error when using "data2":

```
tryCatch_mod(read.csv("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/data2.csv",
                      skip = 2, col.names = c("Date","SOI")))
```

### What I can't figure out

How do I include this function (or something that accomplishes the same thing) so that the output is conditional or whether there is a error? So that is, how do I write my function that it essentially says:

- When there is an error, skip any manipulations and append `i` and the error message into `df`
- When there is NOT an error, perform the manipulation and append results onto the same `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreate your data.frame to include one additional column to store error messages, because in R data.frame, one column should store one type of things. It will be a mess to store error messages and other things in one column, and their type will be coerced to be the same. The `handle_i` function is the function you want to carry out on each `i`. The error-handling is the `tryCatch` line, it returns the error message you want to store whenever error happens (but it doesn't do anything about warning). And finally it will store the things correspondingly to the data.frame.

```
handle_i <- function(i){
    raw <- read.csv(
        paste0("https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/teleconnections/enso/indicators/soi/",i,".csv"),
        skip = 2, col.names = c("Date","SOI") )
    list(mean_soi = mean(raw$SOI))
}

data_spec <- c("data", "data2")
df <- data.frame(data_spec = data_spec, mean_soi = NA, message = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(data_spec)) {
    r <- tryCatch(handle_i(data_spec[i]), error = function(e) list(message = e$message))
    df[i, names(r)] <- r
}
```